# SessionFactory gives null value for one method but not for the other

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, sessionfactory

This is my repository :

```
@Autowired
    private SessionFactory session;

@Override
    public List getAllPersons() {
        return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Person").list();
    }

    @Override
    public List getAllUsers() {
        return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from user").list();
    }
```

And here my `getAllpersons` is working fine and returning values from the database "Person"
But the other method `getAllUsers` is not returning anything from "user" but gives me `null` in the trace log and a `NullpointerException` on the website.

```
log.setLevel(Level.TRACE);
        log.trace("fhfgh");
        log.trace("session : " + session);
        log.trace(session.getCurrentSession().toString());
        log.trace(session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("Select * from user").list());
```

TRACE: root - session : null

How on earth can one method work and return values but the other not and cast `NullpointerException` and `null` in the sessoin factory??

this is my application context :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="se.blobb.civilforsvaret" />   

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close" p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
        p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}" p:password="${jdbc.password}" />
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean> 
    <bean id="messageSource"
        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
         <property name="basename" value="/WEB-INF/messages" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```

and this is my web.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>civilforsvaret</display-name>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And from this method I am calling set `getAllUsers()` that gives me the `NullpointerException`.

```
public boolean ValidateUser(String username, String password){

        boolean success = false;
        List<User> users = service.getAllUsers();


        for(User allUsers : users){

            if(allUsers.getUserName().equals(username) && allUsers.getPassword().equals(password));

            success = true;

        }

        return success;


    }
```

Comment: Where do you get the null pointer? At this line? session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from user").list();

Comment: Yes that line and this one : List<User> users = service.getAllUsers(); But they are both related to that line you quoted and to the sessionFactory.

Comment: your service class is a Spring autowired class correct? So, the nullpointer shouldnt be at the service.getAllUsers() method but this would be in the stacktrace. Also, try setting this attribute hibernate.current_session_context_class to thread, although, its default value is thread. What this will do is set the scope of your session object to be thread based.

Comment: I haven't used SessionFactory myself, but from your code and what you said, I believe the issue is with: createQuery("from user").list(); shouldn't it be instead : createQuery("from User").list();